# Kivy Image displays nothing for some jpg images

Tags: python, kivy, raspberry-pi3

I have a simple Kivy application that loads images one by one from a directory.  Some of the jpg images fail to display on Raspberry Pi 3 when the application is run.  When the application is run from a Mac, all images display fine.

The only differences I have been able to determine between the jpg images is the color profile (sRGB which fails, P3 which works).  Though this may be a red herring.

I have attempted to change the Image Renders to the ones I have available.  The default renderer is SDL2.  I have also tried ffpy and PIL.

This is my Kivy log:

```
[INFO   ] Logger: Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_19-12-23_0.txt
[WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
[WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 21)
[INFO   ] Kivy: v1.11.1
[INFO   ] Kivy: Installed at "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] Python: v3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
[INFO   ] Python: Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] Factory: 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] ImageLoaderFFPy: Using ffpyplayer 4.3.0
[INFO   ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer, img_gif 
[DEBUG  ] App: Loading kv <./carousel.kv>
[DEBUG  ] App: kv <./carousel.kv> not found
[DEBUG  ] Window: Ignored <egl_rpi> (import error)
[INFO   ] Window: Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] GL: Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] GL: Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 2.0'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL vendor <b'Broadcom'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL renderer <b'VideoCore IV HW'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] GL: Shading version <b'OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00'>
[INFO   ] GL: Texture max size <2048>
[INFO   ] GL: Texture max units <8>
[DEBUG  ] Shader: Fragment compiled successfully
[DEBUG  ] Shader: Vertex compiled successfully
[DEBUG  ] ImageSDL2: Load </usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kivy/data/glsl/default.png>
[INFO   ] Window: auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] Window: virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[DEBUG  ] Cache: register <kv.loader> with limit=500, timeout=60
[INFO   ] Loader: using a thread pool of 2 workers
[DEBUG  ] ImagePIL: Load </usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kivy/data/images/image-loading.gif>
[DEBUG  ] Base: Create provider from mouse
[DEBUG  ] Base: Create provider from probesysfs
[DEBUG  ] ProbeSysfs: using probesysfs!
[DEBUG  ] ProbeSysfs: found device: FT5406 memory based driver at /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] ProbeSysfs: device match: /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] MTD: Read event from </dev/input/event0>
[INFO   ] Base: Start application main loop
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> range position X is 0 - 800
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> range position Y is 0 - 480
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> range touch major is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> range touch minor is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> range pressure is 0 - 255
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> axes invertion: X is 0, Y is 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> rotation set to 0
[DEBUG  ] ImageSDL2: Load </photos/01a649559fae77beb14380c489820326ea205ca647.JPG>
[INFO   ] GL: NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] GL: Unpack subimage support is available
root@6fa947ee803c:/usr/src/app# cat /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_19-12-23_0.txt
[INFO   ] Logger: Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_19-12-23_0.txt
[WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
[WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 21)
[INFO   ] Kivy: v1.11.1
[INFO   ] Kivy: Installed at "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] Python: v3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
[INFO   ] Python: Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] Factory: 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] ImageLoaderFFPy: Using ffpyplayer 4.3.0
[INFO   ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer, img_gif 
[DEBUG  ] App: Loading kv <./carousel.kv>
[DEBUG  ] App: kv <./carousel.kv> not found
[DEBUG  ] Window: Ignored <egl_rpi> (import error)
[INFO   ] Window: Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] GL: Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] GL: Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 2.0'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL vendor <b'Broadcom'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL renderer <b'VideoCore IV HW'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] GL: Shading version <b'OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00'>
[INFO   ] GL: Texture max size <2048>
[INFO   ] GL: Texture max units <8>
[DEBUG  ] Shader: Fragment compiled successfully
[DEBUG  ] Shader: Vertex compiled successfully
[DEBUG  ] ImageSDL2: Load </usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kivy/data/glsl/default.png>
[INFO   ] Window: auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] Window: virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[DEBUG  ] Cache: register <kv.loader> with limit=500, timeout=60
[INFO   ] Loader: using a thread pool of 2 workers
[DEBUG  ] ImagePIL: Load </usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kivy/data/images/image-loading.gif>
[DEBUG  ] Base: Create provider from mouse
[DEBUG  ] Base: Create provider from probesysfs
[DEBUG  ] ProbeSysfs: using probesysfs!
[DEBUG  ] ProbeSysfs: found device: FT5406 memory based driver at /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] ProbeSysfs: device match: /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] MTD: Read event from </dev/input/event0>
[INFO   ] Base: Start application main loop
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> range position X is 0 - 800
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> range position Y is 0 - 480
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> range touch major is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> range touch minor is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> range pressure is 0 - 255
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> axes invertion: X is 0, Y is 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> rotation set to 0
[DEBUG  ] ImageSDL2: Load </photos/01a649559fae77beb14380c489820326ea205ca647.JPG>
[INFO   ] GL: NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] GL: Unpack subimage support is available
```

I am not positive what is causing some images to fail to load and any advice on what to try next would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was able to get the images to load by resizing them all down via PIL.  I still don't know why this fixed it as images would display or fail to display even when they were of similar sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this would be your issue, but when I had a problem with some slideshow images not displaying with Kivy on the Raspberry Pi (but working fine with Kivy on Windows), what fixed it was to set nocache = True on the Image instance.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and see what happens with my original code.